# Map the corresponding values of a file in shell script

Tags: shell, loops, unix, awk

My output.txt file is having two columns. I'm trying to add HTML code to change the background color of the cell where the data will be displayed. If the value is greater than 70, I'm adding a red background color and saving that value along with it's corresponding hostname in the .csv file. But, the below code is not working properly as required. What code should I write so that the value along with it's corresponding hostname is saved in the .csv file??

```
Output.txt file:

Hostname, Value
POIDAPP1122,60
POIMAPP150,68
PSSBLEA072,66
PSSBLEA073,65
PSSBLEMA041,66
PSSBLEMA104,60
POIDAPP2120,68
POIMAPP149,60
POAMAPP1121,61
PSSBLEA111,60
PSSBLEAIW133,67
PSSBLEAIW143,61
PSSBLSSOOAMA076,64
PSSBLSSOOIMA200,68
plsbproxyw123,61


for i in `cat $path/output.txt| sed "1 d"`; do
Shostname=$(echo $i |awk '{print $1}');      
Svalue=$(echo $i |awk '{print $2}');      
if [ $Svalue -gt 70 ]
then
echo "Shostname,<div class="c1">$Svalue" >>$path/output_new.csv
elif [ $Svalue -gt 65 ]
then
echo "$Shostname,<div class="w1">$Svalue" >>$path/output_new.csv
then
echo "$Shostname,$Svalue" >>$path/output_new.csv
fi
done

  Getting this output:  


HOSTNAME, SPACE(%)
66  66
66  66
67  67
68  68
68  68
68  68
65
65
65
65
65
65
65
PSSBLEA073  66
PSSBLEA072  66
PSSBLEMA041 66
PSSBLEAIW133    66
PSSBLSSOOIMA200 66
POIDAPP2120 66
POIMAPP150  66
PSSBLEA073  66
PSSBLEA072  66
PSSBLEMA041 66
PSSBLEAIW133    66
PSSBLSSOOIMA200 66
POIDAPP2120 66
POIMAPP150  66
PSSBLEA073  67
PSSBLEA072  67
PSSBLEMA041 67
PSSBLEAIW133    67
PSSBLSSOOIMA200 67
POIDAPP2120 67
POIMAPP150  67
PSSBLEA073  68
PSSBLEA072  68
PSSBLEMA041 68
PSSBLEAIW133    68
PSSBLSSOOIMA200 68
POIDAPP2120 68
POIMAPP150  68
PSSBLEA073  68
PSSBLEA072  68
PSSBLEMA041 68
PSSBLEAIW133    68
PSSBLSSOOIMA200 68
POIDAPP2120 68
POIMAPP150  68
PSSBLEA073  68
PSSBLEA072  68
PSSBLEMA041 68
PSSBLEAIW133    68
PSSBLSSOOIMA200 68
POIDAPP2120 68
POIMAPP150  68
PSSBLEA073  65
PSSBLEA072  66
PSSBLEMA041 66
PSSBLEAIW133    67
PSSBLSSOOIMA200 68
POIDAPP2120 68
POIMAPP150  68

This is my desired output:
  HOSTNAME SPACE(%)
 PSSBLEA073    65
 PSSBLEA072    66
 PSSBLEMA041   66
 PSSBLEAIW133  67
PSSBLSSOOIMA200 68
 POIDAPP2120   68
 POIMAPP150    68
```

Answer (score 3):

With your shown attempts/samples, could you please try following, written and tested with GNU `awk`, should work in any work. Please make sure you have a shell variable named `path` because its being passed to `awk` program as a variable.

```
awk -v pathVal="$path" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  outputFile=pathVal"/output.csv"
}
FNR>1{
  if($2>70){
    print $1 OFS "<div class=\"c1\">" OFS $2 > (outputFile)
  }
  if($2>65 && $2<70){
    print $1 OFS "<div class=\"w1\">" OFS $2 > (outputFile)
  }
}' Input_file
```

Comment: I'm getting the below error after using the code which you gave:+ awk -v pathVal=/app/siebel/PSSBLEA073/ent/scripts/diskspace/diskpace_report $'\nBEGIN{\n  FS=OFS=","\n  outputFile=pathVal"/output.csv"\n}\nFNR>1{\n  if($2>70){\n    print $1 OFS "<div class=\\"c1\\">" OFS $2 > (outputFile)\n  }\n  if($2>65 && $2<70){\n    print $1 OFS "<div class=\\"w1\\">" OFS $2 > (outputFile)\n  }\n}' output.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @ShubhamChaurasia, looks like you are using Sun o.s, please change `awk` to `nawk` in my solution and then run it once?

Comment: This is the code which I gave: path=/app/siebel/PSSBLEA073/ent/scripts/diskspace/diskpace_report
awk -v pathVal="$path" '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=","
  outputFile=pathVal"/output.csv"
}
FNR>1{
  if($2>70){
    print $1 OFS "<div class=\"c1\">" OFS $2 > (outputFile)
  }
  if($2>65 && $2<70){
    print $1 OFS "<div class=\"w1\">" OFS $2 > (outputFile)
  }
}' output.txt

output.txt is my input file

Comment: I don't need this comma b/w the div class and the value due to which div class is not applying to the value POIMAPP150,<div class="w1">,68
PSSBLEA073,<div class="w1">,67
POIDAPP2120,<div class="w1">,68
PSSBLSSOOIMA200,<div class="w1">,68

Comment: @ShubhamChaurasia, you should try like: `path=/app/siebel/PSSBLEA073/ent/scripts/diskspace/diskpace_report; nawk -v pathVal="$path" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=",";outputFile=pathVal"/output.csv"}FNR>1{if($2>70){print $1 OFS "<div class=\"c1\">" OFS $2 > (outputFile)};if($2>65 && $2<70){print $1 OFS "<div class=\"w1\">" OFS $2 > (outputFile)}}'  Input_file` USE `nawk` as you are on Solaris O.S

Comment: I want to add a seperate condition for PWEBF105. If its value is >=70 and <75, I want the div class "w1" to be added whereas if the value is >=75, I want to add the div class "c1". How should I modify the above code??